# Showing a different active field when some answer is selected, Yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have an active form with a radioList. When the option 'other' is selected, I want to show a hidden field, using jquery.
For some reason, what i tried did not work.
My form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'program_motivation', [
        'inputOptions' =>[
            'id' => 'motiv'
        ]
    ])->radioList(array('1'=>'money','2'=>'content','3'=>'other')); ?>


 <?= $form->field($model, 'otherMotiv',['inputOptions' => [
        'id' => 'otherM'
]]))->hiddenInput()->textInput(['maxlength' => 10])->label('insert other option')?>
```

My javascript:

```
var program = $('#motiv').val();
if (program == 'other'){
    $('#otherM').show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1) .val() means value (in your case you have 1, 2 or 3 values). `if (program == 'other')` here you compare text, not values

2)

```
$('input[name="MyModel[program_motivation]"]').change(function() {
   if (this.value == 3)
      $('#otherM').show();
});
```

3) remove `hiddenInput()` and set options:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'otherMotiv',[
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'form-group',
        'style' => 'display: ' . ($model->program_motivation == 3) ? 'block' : 'none')
    ],
    'inputOptions' => [
        'id' => 'otherM'
    ]]))->textInput(['maxlength' => 10])->label('insert other option')?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an hidden input i think you should use a normal textInput but with the css display or  set to none or the visibility  set to hidden or a container div of the textInput set to `visibilty: hidden;` or `display:none;` and then when ypu need  show or the textInput or the container div

First try with an input with css display: hidden;

```
$("#otherM").attr("display","inline"); or
$("#otherM").attr("visibility","visible");
```

or

```
$("#idContainerDiv").attr("display","block"); or
$("#idContainerDiv").attr("visibility","visible");
```

Comment: This is surely exactly what `$('#otherM').show();` does!